# Google App Script Search UI Tool with Previous Function ERROR

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Previous Function is working but when i'm going to click previous for the last sesrch of it. im getting an error 'CANNOT CALL METHOD 'toString of undefined.
Please help with my code. Im having a trial and error with the highlighted code below in the previous function. please help thank you.

```
function click(eventInfo){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qpx2qZvBriBZ3jkOfHjMpsRbL9w04JZEJMeor11OJC81').getSheetByName("Teaching");
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();    
 var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
        app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");                                                                                            

  var item = eventInfo.parameter.itemname;
   var next = app.getElementById("nextid").setEnabled(false);
   var pre = app.getElementById("previd").setEnabled(false);
   var lbl = app.getElementById("lblid").setText("No match"); 
   var f1 = eventInfo.parameter.thirdname;
  var f2 = eventInfo.parameter.fourthname;
  var f3 = eventInfo.parameter.fifthname;
  var f4 = eventInfo.parameter.emailname;
  var f1box = app.getElementById("thirdid");
  var f2box = app.getElementById("fourthid");
  var f3box = app.getElementById("fifthid");
  var f4box = app.getElementById("emailid");
    var hidden = app.getElementById("hidden");                  
   var data = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow,6).getValues();// get the 3 columns of data
       for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){ ;// iterate trough
         if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!='') {;// if a match is found in one of the 3 fields, break the loop and show results
  f1box.setText(data[nn][2]);         
  f2box.setText(data[nn][3]);   
  f3box.setText(data[nn][4]); 
  f4box.setText(data[nn][5]); 
      app.getElementById("nextid").setEnabled(true).setText("Next");                                                                                            
      app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");                                                                                            
           ss.getRange(nn+2,2).activate();
            lbl.setText("found from"+data[nn][0]+"-"+data[nn][1]+", click Next").setEnabled(true);
          hidden.setValue(nn.toString())  
          break;}}
  return app;
}
function next(eventInfo){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qpx2qZvBriBZ3jkOfHjMpsRbL9w04JZEJMeor11OJC81').getSheetByName("Teaching");
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();    
 var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
        app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");                                                                                            

  var item = eventInfo.parameter.itemname;
   var next = app.getElementById("nextid").setText("No match").setEnabled(false);
   var pre = app.getElementById("previd").setEnabled(true);
   var lbl = app.getElementById("lblid").setText("0 results to display"); 
   var f1 = eventInfo.parameter.thirdname;
  var f2 = eventInfo.parameter.fourthname;
  var f3 = eventInfo.parameter.fifthname;
  var f4 = eventInfo.parameter.emailname;
  var f1box = app.getElementById("thirdid").setText("");
  var f2box = app.getElementById("fourthid").setText("");
  var f3box = app.getElementById("fifthid").setText("");
  var f4box = app.getElementById("emailid").setText("");
    var start = Number(eventInfo.parameter.hidden)+1;
    var hidden = app.getElementById("hidden");                  
   var data = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow,6).getValues();// get the 3 columns of data
       for(nn=start;nn<data.length;++nn){ ;// iterate trough
         if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!='') {;// if a match is found in one of the 3 fields, break the loop and show results
  f1box.setText(data[nn][2]);         
  f2box.setText(data[nn][3]);   
  f3box.setText(data[nn][4]); 
  f4box.setText(data[nn][5]); 
         app.getElementById("previd").setEnabled(true).setText("Previous");                                                                                                
      app.getElementById("nextid").setEnabled(true).setText("Next");                                                                                                
      app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");                                                                                            
           ss.getRange(nn+2,2).activate();
            lbl.setText("found from"+data[nn][0]+"-"+data[nn][1]+", click Next").setEnabled(true);
          hidden.setValue(nn.toString())  
          break;}}
  return app;
}
function previous(eventInfo){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qpx2qZvBriBZ3jkOfHjMpsRbL9w04JZEJMeor11OJC81').getSheetByName("Teaching");
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();    
 var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
        app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");                                                                                            

  var item = eventInfo.parameter.itemname;
   var next = app.getElementById("nextid").setEnabled(true);
   var pre = app.getElementById("previd").setText("No match").setEnabled(false);
   var lbl = app.getElementById("lblid").setText("No match"); 
   var f1 = eventInfo.parameter.thirdname;
  var f2 = eventInfo.parameter.fourthname;
  var f3 = eventInfo.parameter.fifthname;
  var f4 = eventInfo.parameter.emailname;
  var f1box = app.getElementById("thirdid").setText("");
  var f2box = app.getElementById("fourthid").setText("");
  var f3box = app.getElementById("fifthid").setText("");
  var f4box = app.getElementById("emailid").setText("");
```

> ```
> var start = Number(eventInfo.parameter.hidden)-1;
>         var hidden = app.getElementById("hidden");                  
>          var data = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow,6).getValues();// get the 3 columns of data
>
>
>
>        for(nn=start;nn<data.length;--nn){ ;// iterate trough***
>
> if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!='')
> ```
>
> {;// if a match is found in one of the 3 fields, break the loop andshoresults
>         f1box.setText(data[nn][2]);
>         f2box.setText(data[nn][3]);
>         f3box.setText(data[nn][4]); 
>         f4box.setText(data[nn][5]); 
>             app.getElementById("previd").setEnabled(true).setText("Previous");
>
> ```
>       app.getElementById("nextid").setEnabled(true).setText("Next");        
>
>       app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");       
>
>              ss.getRange(nn+2,2).activate();
>             lbl.setText("found from"+data[nn][0]+"-"+data[nn][1]+", click Next").setEnabled(true);
>           hidden.setValue(nn.toString())  
>           break;}}
> ```

return app;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating the data array with index nn but the last item of this array is empty because of the way the array is built.
When you declare it using

```
var data = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow,6).getValues();// get the 3 columns of data
```

you start from row 2 and get lastRow value for length which means data contains the empty row below the last one (lastRow returns the total height of filled data range).

try using `var data = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow-1,6)` and it should solve the issue

note : this is a (modified) code I originally wrote a few years ago, not sure I made that mistake in the original script ;-)

Comment: im still getting the error cannot call method toSting of undefined. Should i also edit other code? I should get "no match" when it will be the last result for the Previous button.. please help thanks

Comment: can i get a copy of your previous function?or can you paste it here so i can see whats my error.  its a big help.. :(  please check my highlighted code from the above... thanks Sir Serge. var start = Number(eventInfo.parameter.hidden)-1;      or   for(nn=start;nn<data.length;--nn)   ??

Comment: I can't find my original script in the right version but if you want you can share a copy of your spreadsheet (in read only and without private data) and show the link here.

Comment: this is my sample spreadsheet = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bAcfcbn8Sqm2RhqgxPzOZO-7VE2e_RbFR7LK5MY0RR0/edit?usp=sharing                                                my Script link = https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxOFbRts8jo2NVn6U8LSW16RBtsfeE2pdhN-M8WtqnpjiomSXQ6/exec    (it's also in the spreadsheet.) thanks for the help and time. Can i get your email? so i can easily contact you with this prob?thankyou @Serge insas